# Loop flow control

Tags: arrays, loops, control-flow

I have an array of objects, each object has a function that returns a Boolean value. What I need to do, is have a loop continuously running until each object returns a true value when the function is called on each object.

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant that I want the loop to break, when ALL of the objects functions return true.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question, you can do like this...

```
do
{
  test = 0;
  for(all functions)
  {
    char test_array[] = function_call();
  }
  int i = 0;
  for(test_array.length)
  {

    if(test_array[i] == true)
    {
      count_no_true = i++;
    }
  }
  if(count_no_true == no of function)
  {test == 1;}
  else
  {test == 0;}    
}while(test == 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Java style syntax:

```
boolean good;
while (true) {
    good = true;
    foreach (MyObject o : myArray) {
        if (!o.someFunction()) {
            good = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (good) break;
}
```

I interpreted it as meaning that every object needed to have its function evaluated to true each time, and once they all evaluate to true break out of the loop.